# React: Set default proptype for array

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

In React I can set default PropTypes like so:

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    multiple: false
}
```

Now, one of my Props is an associative array. I want to set the default value for one of the key value pars, for example:

```
ImageMultiCheck.defaultProps = {
    multiple: false,
    myArray: {label: 'default Value'}
}
```

This is not working. Maybe its just a syntax mistake. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default props is only used if no props are passed in for that specific property. If you are passing in a prop of `myArray` but the object has no key/value pair for `label` then you would have two options:

You could handle that case in the parent component and do a check to see if label exists on the object being passed down and if not add the default. Otherwise in your `ImageMultiCheck` component you would have to do some sort of `var label = myArray.label ? myArray.label : 'default value'`

Since it is a prop you don't want to mutate your `myArray` object by doing something like `myArray.label = 'default value' in the`ImageMultiCheck` component hence why I suggested using a ternary assignment operation on a variable.

Comment: Thank you @finalfreq, that explains it well. You are right in saying that I do not want to change the actual state of the label. So in my ImageMultiCheck I will just place a default-string in case the label-prop is missing.